# Python: loop over dictionary of strings to declare variable name

Tags: python, string, for-loop, variables

I declare two variables via

```
self.var_country_AT = BooleanVar(value=self.parameter.country_AT)
self.var_country_IT = BooleanVar(value=self.parameter.country_IT)
```

Is there a possibility to loop over AT and IT in the following sense:

```
countries = {'AT', 'IT'}
for c in countries:
  self.var_country_c = BooleanVar(value=self.parameter.country_c)
```

This does not work of course. Generally, I need to glue the string to a variable name.

Comment: Use a dictionary like `self.countries['AT']`.

Comment: How do I deal with the country name (c) on the right hand side?

Comment: The depends on what `self.parameter` is.